# How did Lois Lane know Lex Luthor has Martha Kent as hostage?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

In *Batman V Superman: Dawn of Justice*, after Superman saved Lois from the fall, he dropped her down and he went back to fight Luthor ... During that time Luthor reveals that he has Martha as hostage and he asked Superman to kill Batman.

Then Superman came down and said to Lois that he has to go to Gotham and kill Batman or convince him to help him but he never mentioned a word about Martha. So how come Lois knows that Luthor has Martha and how come she came and saved Superman from Batman during the fight?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So how come Lois knows that Luthor has Martha?

### She didn't

The only thing she says is that Martha is Superman's mother's name. At no point does she say Luthor kidnapped her.

In fact it's Superman who explains to Batman...

> He [Luthor] wanted her life for yours.

So basically, Lois finds out because Superman told Batman and she was there when he did it.